# specflow table.CreateSet<object> mapping column name mismatches

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am using specflow and  have a simple table:

```
FirstName | Surname|
Bob       | Dylan  |
```

and a class as follows:

```
public class Person{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and the code i want to run is:

```
var people = table.CreateSet<Person>();
```

Question:

How do I map surname from the table to LastName in the object?

Cheers

Comment: Specflow doesn't have any apis that I'm aware of that let you perform that kind of mappings. There are some workarounds (like having a `Surname` property and make `LastName` be a computed property that returns `Surname`), but I consider that they're more painful than using `LastName` as your table column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas Willich who has said the ability to add the alias will be added in a future release.

Until then, i have looked at the signatures for the methods and it does allow you to specify a function which will allow a hard coded mapping as follows which isn't the clean solution i was looking for but it fixed what i needed it to do:

```
    var people = table.CreateSet<Person>(ConvertMethod);

..... //return type is the same as you want and method takes a Tablerow as a parameter
    public static Person ConvertMethod(TableRow row)
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            FirstName = row["firstName"],
            LastName = row["surname"]
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of SpecFlow 2.2.1) this is not possible.
But we got a PR two weeks ago, that will add the possibility to specific a "mapping" between column name and property.
The code is here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/969

It is not fix that we will merge this PR, but currently there are no showstoppers for not doing this.

Feedback to this PR is welcomed!